# Changing screen resolution/geometry of a vncserver without randr in Linux

Tags: linux, vnc

I want to change the resolution / geometry of my VNC session dynamically without affecting the programs running inside it.

I referred: [Changing the resolution of a VNC session in linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15816/changing-the-resolution-of-a-vnc-session-in-linux).
I don't have root permission to update the newer vncserver version, so following command doesn't work as of now:

```
vncserver -geometry 1280x1024 -randr 1280x1024,1280x800
```

For now, whenever I want to change the screen size from one monitor to other, I kill the session and restart it with modified `-geometry` option. Due to this I have to loose the programs inside it.

Is there any way to hack the file which stores the geometry and change the values for changing the resolution? I couldn't find such file. In my home folder, I see below files:

```
mgandhi@starbase:~/.vnc$ ll
total 12
-rwxr-xr-x 1 mgandhi bc  334 Jun 25 10:32 xstartup
-rw------- 1 mgandhi bc    8 Jun 25 10:32 passwd
-rw-r--r-- 1 mgandhi bc    6 Jun 25 11:08 starbase.radisys.com:23.pid
-rw-r--r-- 1 mgandhi bc 1664 Jun 25 11:08 starbase.radisys.com:23.log
```

The contents of `xstartup` file doesn't help:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Uncomment the following two lines for normal desktop:
# unset SESSION_MANAGER
# exec /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc

[ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup
[ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xsetroot -solid grey
vncconfig -iconic &
xterm -geometry 80x24+10+10 -ls -title "$VNCDESKTOP Desktop" &
twm &
```

... here `xterm -geometry 80x24+10+10 -ls -title "$VNCDESKTOP Desktop" &` line remains constant for any resolution.

[Note: I see that `xrandr` is installed in the linux machine.]

Answer (score 7):

A "Hack" solution: start the vncserver without any specified geometry

```
vncserver :1
```

Then I'll connect to the vnc, and in Fedora, I'll just go into Settings>Displays>Unknown 0"
and change the resolution on the fly like this. Take some clicking rather than typing (DX), but its easy.

Comment: This option result to "cannot determine the xrandr version" and nothing more :-/ (Debian 8) but looks interesting.

Answer (score 2):

The answer above for Fedora did not work for me (RedHat Enterprise), I was able to accomplish what you need in these steps:

1) log into your VNC session (existing)

2) open a terminal and type:
xrandr -s 1920x1080  (or another supported geometry/display*)

to see randr supported displays/resolutions, type:

xrandr (with no arguments)

Easy, and nothing fancy!

Answer (score 1):

Set the geometry option in the systemd configuration file (or otherwise applicable startup script) ~ this example works with Fedora 28 (assuming selinux file descriptors are fixed).

Replace USERNAME with the actual username:

```
cat /etc/systemd/system/vncserver@\:1.service

[Unit]
Description=Remote desktop service (VNC)
After=syslog.target network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
User=USERNAME

# Clean any existing files in /tmp/.X11-unix environment
ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c '/usr/bin/vncserver -kill %i > /dev/null 2>&1 || :'
ExecStart=/usr/bin/vncserver %i -geometry 1280x1024
PIDFile=/home/USERNAME/.vnc/%H%i.pid
ExecStop=/bin/sh -c '/usr/bin/vncserver -kill %i > /dev/null 2>&1 || :'

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Answer (score 0):

`$HOME/.vnc/xstartup` is the file you are looking for and yes, you can set the geometry there. It should adjust on reconnect without borking your session (not 100% sure but pretty sure).

Comment: It would be more helpful to show than to tell.